# JQuery and business application like ERP - Kendo UI

Tags: jquery, silverlight, kendo-ui, erp

I am looking for some solutions to make some modular and with easy to change design layout business application (ERP).

I was learning last few months (in some another business small project) Silverlight using all of the benefits of MVVM pattern. I like it a lot, validation, two way binding etc, all this stuff is very good. There were problems when Silverlight have to cooperate with RESTfull service created in some other technology like java or php and not RIA and WCF services. I mean controls in silverlight are very tight fit to RIA services. All what you get at start have to be done in some other way and "RIA" features begin disturb you.

Another problem is the future of Silverlight which is uncertain. New big erp application have to live some long time, additionally some small modules of application have to work in some mobile devices. I nowadays all of that can be done in HTML5 and javascript without making a lot of small native apps for all of kind devices.

I saw last week framework Kendo UI -> [KENDOUI](http://www.kendoui.com/)

I wonder if this is not the solution to the problem?
Framework with good looking business controls and MVVM. I started to making some test with trial and looks good, have some small disadvantages, like not implemented easy to change component's language, too rigidly fixed communication with web services based on WCF in DataService but I can live with that. The only thing I'm afraid of use Kendo in new project is newness of the product. It seems that a lot still needs to be done that it can be used in serious project. But maybe I'm wrong so for that I have created that thread.

Are there any other solutions that will fit to my needs? Some another jquery widget framework? Infragistic jquery controls seems to be interesting but I have not checked them.

Comment: I would go with an open source ERP and just learn how the themes work.. you could save some time and headaches starting from something instead of redoing all over again. I'm sure you will forget plenty and not in 6 month you will have a stable version...

Comment: very specific needs to use a ready solution